# Show waiting message when hitting toggle in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

My UI is not updating until after the loading takes place, therefor defeating the purpose of the waiting message.

```
- (IBAction)toggle:(UISwitch *)sender {

    [self.waitingMsg setHidden:NO];//UI should update here to show waiting message

    [ThirdViewController scheduleNotifications:[NSDate date]];

    //Unfortunatly UI is not getting updating until the processing.
}
```

How do I immediately update the UI before the processing begins?

Comment: What exactly are you going to be processing?

Comment: I am scheduling notifications, I don't understand why the UI does not set my waiting message to be visible when I tell it to.

Comment: Are you actually running the toggle method from the switch action? Or are you running it from code? If you're running it from code could you please paste the code that is running it. Thanks

Comment: It is a toggle method driven from the xib file.

Comment: OK, just checking it wasn't running on the wrong thread.

Comment: Maybe try `[self.waitingMessage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setHidden:) withObject:NO waitUntilDone:YES];`?

Comment: Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the user interface is not actually drawn / updated until after your code finishes running. So:

```
[self.waitingMsg setHidden:NO]; // this is just a command for what WILL happen
[ThirdViewController scheduleNotifications:[NSDate date]]; // but now ...
// ... your code keeps running...
// ... so nothing can happen until AFTER scheduleNotifications returns
```

The solution is to cycle the runloop once, giving drawing a chance to take place. Like this:

```
 [self.waitingMsg setHidden:NO];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [ThirdViewController scheduleNotifications:[NSDate date]];
    /// ... and all the rest of your code goes here...
 });
```

Comment: And see my book on this topic, which is called "delayed performance": http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch11.html#_delayed_performance

Comment: Ah, I actually didn't know this. Although it does make sense.

Comment: For more detail on when drawing actually takes place (I call this the "redraw moment"): http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_drawing_animation_and_threading

Comment: This solution does not work in practice, thanks anyway.

Comment: Any other work arounds that might work? Seems like these type of dispatch solutions are convoluted.

Comment: There should be a call or something to refresh the UI or another event that happens before the processing.

Comment: It does work. This *is* the call that refreshes the UI. If it doesn't work for you, you are doing it wrong. But, as I already said, see my discussion of delayed performance in my book: `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` is one of the ways that I list, though in my opinion it is far and away the clumsiest, least flexible, and least readable of the three options I give.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, see code below:

```
- (IBAction)toggle:(UISwitch *)sender {

    [self.waitingMsg setHidden:NO];//UI should update here to show waiting message

    [self performSelector:@selector(scheduleFromToggle:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}


- (void)scheduleFromToggle:(id)sender {

    [ThirdViewController scheduleNotifications:[NSDate date]];

    [self.waitingMsg setHidden:YES];

}
```